# M-V-VM best practices

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I found two ways to use M-V-VM pattern in WPF:

1. allocate the ViewModel into the View's code behind (setting it as the DataContext);
2. allocate the ViewModel into a XAML file and create the corresponding view using a DataTemplate.

The Model can be allocated into the ViewModel's constructor.

What do you think about this way of using M-V-VM pattern? What are best practices relative to it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to follow #2 and have found it to be the most flexible. As a best practice I would move these `DataTemplate`'s into `ResourceDictionary`'s so they can be shared amongst XAML that will require them.

Answer (score 1):

Method #3 is what we do:

This is with Boo / Binsor... the datacontext is setup through IOC.

```
component "AngleRoomModel", IRoomViewModel, AngleRoomViewModel
component "AngleRoom", IRoomView, AngleRoomView:  
  DataContext = @AngleRoomModel
```

Comment: Nice job! I found the Cailburn project you're talking about: http://caliburn.codeplex.com/